# File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it ionic 3

Tags: android, json, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for push notification I always get this error message

> "File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin
>   cannot function without it ionic 3"

on phone I have placed my google-services.json on every folder and nothings working

Comment: i meant phone gap

Answer (score 23):

Fist of all you need to download google-services.json:

1. Sign in to Firebase and open your project.
2. Click the Settings icon and select Project settings.
3. In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app you need a config file for from the list.
4. Click google-services.json.

(https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592)

Ok now you have to install cordova-support-google-services:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-support-google-services --save
```

Then, you have to put the google-services.json in the root of your project (outside www folder, at the same level), and then the resource-file tag will copy it to platforms/android/app/

Next, put in the config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
 ... 
 </platform>
```

Note: if you use cordova-android below version 7 specify instead:

> target="google-services.json"

Now try again to build!

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been struggling for hours in solving this issue but your notes hit the nail right on the head!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you!

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned before `google-services.json` needs to be copied to the proper location. the location changed recently to `app/google-services.json`. So the `config.xml` needs to be adapted accordingly to

```
<resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
```

Comment: hello Daniel, so, the google-services.json file is required in ionic 1, too?

Answer (score 2):

Lets' assume you put the google-services.json in src/app folder
So relativly to your ionic project it is located at **src/app/google-services.json**

Now, to be sure it will be copied to the correct location of the build, you have to add a line of code to the config.xml file.

```
<resource-file src="src/app/google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
```

Note that the **src** property of this line should reflect the relative path of the google-service.json file accordingly.

That's as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

Place the `google-services.json` file in your project's root and make sure it will be copied to the `www` directory by adding this line to the `config.xml` file (between the `<platform name="android">...</platform>` tags):

```
<resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
```

then run `ionic cordova prepare android` again.

Answer (score 0):

From your dropdown select

- project
- then go to app folder
- then paste your file inside app folder.
- clean build and rebuild again

[image]

Comment: my project is on Ionic 3 and i have already done pasting everywhere the file plus adding it on conifg.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have placed `google-services.json` in `Platforms/Android/` folder and `run ionic cordova build android`. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the google-services.json file into platforms/android/app folder. Executing a android run will work fine.

(You can download the google-services.json from firbase project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your `google-services.json` inside of your `ionicProject/src` then try to remove and reinstall the `ionic-firebase` plugin again.

Answer (score 0):

Add **google-services.json** file where the config.xml file is

Then add this line to the config.xml file

```
<platform name="android">
         <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
```

Then go to **Project/platforms/android** and add the **google-services.json** file