# Ionic 5 with FCM

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I try to Add FCM to my application using Capacitor

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm

I add the google servies.json to android\app

i change the code
from `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`
To `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'`
as firebase documentation

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

try to run the application in emulater but i got error in android studio

```
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location: 
C:\Users\User\Documents\IONICProject\sahha-admin\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\User\Documents\IONICProject\sahha-admin\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\User\Documents\IONICProject\sahha-admin\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
C:\Users\User\Documents\IONICProject\sahha-admin\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\User\Documents\IONICProject\sahha-admin\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
C:\Users\User\Documents\IONICProject\sahha-admin\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\google-services.json
```

Environment :

win 10
Mobile android version: 9
Cordova CLI version : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
IONIC version : 6.10.1
Android Studio version :4.0.1

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "sahha-admin",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
   

     "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
        "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
        "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
        "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
        "@capacitor-community/fcm": "^1.0.8",
        "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.0",
        "@capacitor/core": "2.4.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
        "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/globalization": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.27.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.8",
        "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
        "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.3",
        "firebase": "^7.22.1",
        "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
        "sweetalert2": "^9.17.1",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
        "@angular/cli": "~9.1.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.6",
        "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.6",
        "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.0",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~3.8.3"
      },
      "description": "An Ionic 

projects"
    }
```

Comment: Are you using cordova or capacitor?  If your are using the capacitor plugin this resolved my issue. https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm/issues/56#issuecomment-724369310

Answer (score 1):

as per   show your question, I also have the same problem a few months ago and I fixed with
following steps.

1). first, remove fcm plugin from the project

2). download the google-services.json file from firebase console

3). put the google-services.json file on the root folder of the project

4). also put in platform/android/ folder

then install fcm plugin and clean build and rebuild again

this process is working for me to try and if not working then also refer the following link it's helped me and maybe you.

[File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647964/file-google-services-json-is-missing-the-google-services-plugin-cannot-function)

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/219

Comment: thanks Mayank, this because I used Capacitor this FCM working in cordova only   https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/issues/183

Comment: okk , may be this example helpful for fcm Integration in ionic with capacitor 
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase
have nice day!!

Comment: Having the problem with iOS does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Hi, @M.Mariscal can you add more info here which type of problem you are facing so we can help you or guide easily.

Comment: /Users/manel/Documents/ionic_projects/project/platforms/ios/ProjectApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/AppDelegate+FCMPlugin.m:146:101: Nullability specifier 'nonnull' conflicts with existing specifier 'nullable' on      is the error on XCode when I am trying to do the build (Ionic 5 with angular)